# After redeploying a FireMonkey app to my physical device, GetDocumentsPath always contains older asset files

Tags: android, delphi, deployment, firemonkey

I'm developing a Delphi FireMonkey app and I'm testing it using some assets. It seems to work fine.

However, now I completely removed all assets from the Deployment Manager and whenever I remove the app from my device (using some ADB shell commands, I can verify that the app directory is completely removed) and run the app again in debug from the IDE, some older assets appear again. (in fact, 1 SQLite database file and a tmp file representing the form savestate. They have normal file attributes, but the file dates are 1970-01-19).

Using the ADB shell command again, I notice these files reappear BEFORE the app hits the `StartupCopy` unit initialization!

I've verified many things, but I have no idea where they keep re-appearing from (from Android itself or transferred from my PC, but since I removed them all, this is very unlikely).

I'm very puzzled with this. If I delete only the data files from the app on the device, this does not happen. Only when I completely remove the app.

Is there a backup/init/loading mechanism on Android itself that might cause this? Since my device is not rooted, looking on the device itself is limited.

`ls -l` of my app's directory:

```
-rw------- 1 u0_a289 u0_a289      4 1970-01-19 03:56 FM_TMainForm_MainForm.TMP
-rw------- 1 u0_a289 u0_a289 217088 1970-01-19 03:45 dancegenie.sqlite
```

Comment: I'm using Delphi Rio 10.2, android 9. PS the directory is the data/data/com.embarcadero.xxxx/files directory

Comment: I also verified all the messages during deployment like 'paclient' and none of them is about these files concerned. I've cleaned the code, deleted the debug directories but the issue keeps returning...

Comment: If I switch to release configuration this does no longer happen. So I think there is some '.../android/debug...' content left behind ( the paclient messages point to putting content in this directory ) but no idea where this directory is on the device, nor to fully clean it for my app

Comment: Thx Remy for the 'pretty print' adjustments :)